# C++ Application compile error :cannot find -lpthread

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse with CDT and MinGW on Windows 7. I wrote a simple program, but it does not run.

Comment: Make sure you use the `-pthread` flag everywhere instead, instead of specifying `-lpthread` for the linker only.

Comment: thank you very much! I have find so many answers recently

Answer (score 1):

**A. First, make sure that include paths are known by Eclipse.**

The following instructions are detailed in https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html but I am including them here for clarity:

Select "Project" menu ⇒ Properties ⇒ C/C++ General ⇒ Paths and Symbols ⇒ In "Includes" tab

1. "Add" the following directories to "GNU C", where $MINGW_HOME is your MinGW installed directory (replace *version_number* by the version used on your system):

   - $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\version_number\include
   - $MINGW_HOME\include
   - $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\version_number\include-fixed
2. "Add" the following directories to "GNU C++", where $MINGW_HOME is your Cygwin installed directory:

   - $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\version_number\include\c++
   - $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\version_number\include\c++\mingw32
   - $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\version_number\include\c++\backward
   - $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\version_number\include
   - $MINGW_HOME\include
   - $MINGW_HOME\lib\gcc\mingw32\version_number\include-fixed

**B. If Eclipse cannot find make**

- You may have to make a copy of C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe as C:\MinGW\bin\make.exe
- Also, add MinGW\bin to your Windows PATH environment variable

**C. You may have to install the pthread library from the MinGW package installer.**

1. Go to your MinGW installation folder (default is C:\MinGW)
2. In the \bin folder, launch the MinGW installation manager by double-clicking on **mingw-get.exe**
3. In the "All Packages" list, select the `mingw32-libpthreadgc` package and "Mark for installation"
4. In the "Installation" menu, click on "Apply Changes"
5. Restart Eclipse